# Why doesn't Ubuntu Software Center have Anaconda?

Tags: software-center, anaconda

I want to install Anaconda without using terminal. I looked in the Software Center but Anaconda wasn't there. What I want to know is why isn't Anaconda in the Software Center?

Comment: Why should it be there?

Answer (score 5):

Software in the Software Center is available in [four main repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu):

- Main - Canonical-supported free and open-source software.
- Universe - Community-maintained free and open-source software.
- Restricted - Proprietary drivers for devices.
- Multiverse - Software restricted by copyright or legal issues.

The scope of each repository is described in detail in the link above. While it would be theoretically possible to provide a larger number of applications, each application requires work because

> the software is thoroughly tested and built specifically for each
>   version of Ubuntu

Clearly then, there are limits to what will or won't be included. And since Anaconda, [being an installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(installer)) used by systems such as CentOS, Fedora and RedHat, is not required by Debian-based systems such as Ubuntu (which uses [Ubiquity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquity_(software)) as its installer), it's exclusion isn't surprising.